# How to focus on a specific input text after the component is rendered?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I'm struggling to make this work properly every time I rendered the component by pushing it using the router object something like this `this.$router.push('/Home/mypath');` which will focus only on the first input text element with index = 0 after the component is rendered even if I passed another value for index. Basically, I passed an index value to the **ref** of the input text element which is inside the **v-for** loop of a component and so at `mounted()`, I have something like this

```
mounted() {
  this.$nextTick(() => 
  {                
      this.$refs.newInp[index].focus();          
    });
  }
```

but it keeps focusing on the first input element even though I passed a value of 1 or 2. When I looked at the console log, it shows this error on the console.
***TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined***
pointing on this line `this.$refs.newInp[index].focus();`

**Sample Code to fetch the data in the v-for**

```
async GetContentDetails() {
     let testRes =
         await axios.get('myUrl/api', {
              params: {
                   ContentId: this.$cookie.get('OpV-ContId')
                      }
                 }).then(res => this.contentItems = res.data)
                      .then()
                      .catch(error => console.log(error));
                this.testData = testRes;
}
```

**Template:**

```
<div v-for="(contItem, index) in contentItems" :key="contItem.commentId">
  <textarea class="reply-commented" ref="newInp"></textarea>
  </div>
```

How to fix this type of issues? What is the solution for this?
Thanks.

Comment: Put minimum code to understand

Comment: @Rahul - what code do u need more? That is the only code I used to focus. which part did you not understand?

Comment: Is your data for v-for loop fetched asynchronously, as in this case the input fields would be created after the data is fetched and the field won't be accessible in mounted hook and thus the error. if not, can you reproduce it in some fiddle?

Comment: `newInp` is undefined. Maybe a `v-if` or something like that. Could we see the template?

Comment: @Himanshu - yes, the data being fetch in the v-for loop uses async, just like this
async GetContentDetails() {
                let testRes =
                    await axios.get('myUrl/api', {
                        params: {
                            ContentId: this.$cookie.get('OpV-ContId')
                        }
                    }).then(res => this.contentItems = res.data)
                        .then()
                        .catch(error => console.log(error));
                this.testData = testRes;
}

Comment: <div v-for="(contItem, index) in contentItems " :key="contItem.commentId">
 .../// some elements here including the input text box.
  </div>

Comment: There is no `ref="newInp"` in your template.

Comment: @Himanshu -
 <div v-for="(contItem, index) in commentItems" :key="contItem.commentId">
  <textarea class="reply-commented" ref="newInp"></textarea>
  </div>

Comment: that's the format of my template in the component.

Comment: So if I used async to fetch the data in the v-for. Is there any ways to focus the element when the component is rendered?

Comment: You can `watch` a reactive state. You added the `vuejs3` tag to your question. Do you use the composition API?

Comment: @Paleo - kindly see my updated post.

Comment: @timmack Can you call the focus input function after you've made the API call? This way the input fields would be there in template and you should be able to use the refs properly

Comment: @Himanshu...I did try that but the same error would still occur.

Comment: I tried something like this but same error would still occur.
async GetComment2() {
                let testRes = await axios.get('myurl/api/GetContent/GetComments').then(res => this.commentItems = res.data).then(this.GetReply2())
                        .catch(error => console.log(error));
                this.testData = testRes.data;
             
                this.$nextTick(() => {
                     this.$refs.newRep[index].focus();                  
                });
            },

Comment: @Paleo -  do u have a sample code that implements watch in a reactive state?

Comment: So your question is not related to Vuejs 3.
Maybe you could just use the Vue lifecyle hook `updated`. See the schema in the documentation.
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html

Comment: @timmack Can you use await for the part where you've used .then as the .then is resolved in the background and when your function is trying to focus on input field it might not be available and I don't think keeping it in the updated hook would be a good idea as that hook would run on every change in the template and would make your app heavy.

Comment: @Himanshu...I'm not sure what you are suggesting. Do u mean within the .then() promise it is where I call my focus function?

Comment: I am suggesting to use await rather than .then and also I couldn't see contentItems in this code that you shared, It is there in your question but not here unless getReply2 is handling that.

async GetComment2() { let testRes = await axios.get('myurl/api/GetContent/GetComments').then(res => this.commentItems = res.data).then(this.GetReply2()) .catch(error => console.log(error)); this.testData = testRes.data; this.$nextTick(() => { this.$refs.newRep[index].focus(); }); },

Comment: @Himanshu -  that is only the sample format of the code when fetching the data for the v-for loop. But still can't figure out your suggestion on how to use await rather than .then(). Can u give me a sample code snippet for that? You can modify the sample code I put above.

Comment: You can't just replace the .then() with await keyword, it will have an error.

Comment: let testRes = await axios.get('myUrl/api', { params: {
                   ContentId: this.$cookie.get('OpV-ContId')
                      } });
this.contentItems = testRes.data

can you keep your code like this? I assume testRes would be giving you the response. and use try catch accordingly instead of .then and .catch

Comment: hmmm...not really sure if that's relevant to the focus behavior. Just give me the same focus behavior after the component is being rendered.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205069/discussion-between-himanshu-and-timmack).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For few days of research and thorough testing and observation on DOM behavior on how vue.js renders component and of course basing on the suggestions from other folks on this thread. I realized you **can't** really focus in the created/mounted properties on a specific index of an element within the for loop particulary in this case the input text element if the data being fetch to bind on the component is coming from the server due to its asynchronous behavior and you have to wait until the component is completely rendered. So I found a solution at least on my case to use a dynamic watcher either in the created or mounted properties and set a dummy or duplicate data properties for the default change of the data properties for the purpose of only to activate the watcher to focus on the specific element after the component has been rendered. This how it looks like. Hope this help to folks that encountering the same scenario as me.

```
created() {           
            this.GetContentDetails();
            this.$watch('commentItems2', function () {
                this.$nextTick(() => {
                    this.$refs.newRep[mapCredential.state.index2].focus();
                });
            });
        },

methods: {
 async GetComment2() {
                let testRes =
                    await axios.get('myUrl/api/GetContent/GetComments')
                        .then(this.GetReply2())
                        .catch(error => console.log(error));
                this.commentItems = testRes.data;
                this.commentItems2 = testRes.data;
            },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood, you want to focus a `textarea` after fetching some data, that said trying to focus inside the `mounted` method wont work because you can't tell if the data has been fetch and the `textarea`s already exist in the DOM.

So the best way to do this is to focus after being sure the data has been fetched, inside the `then` callback.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  data: {
    posts: [],
    index: 3 // Change this to focus whatever textarea you want
  },
  
  mounted () {
    this.fetchItems();
  },
  
  methods: {
    fetchItems () {
      const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'

      axios.get(url).then(response => {
        this.posts = response.data
        
        this.$nextTick(_ => {
          this.$refs.newInp[this.index].focus()
        })
      })
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="app"> 
  <div v-for="(post, index) in posts" :key="post.id">
    <textarea class="reply-commented" ref="newInp" v-text="post.body"></textarea>
  </div> 
</div>



<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Comment: It is still necessary to test if the fetched list is empty.

Comment: Yes. You can test if there are items at the template level or inside the callback

Comment: @HelderLucas...that is the same code I used but again the issue is it always focus on the first element which is at index = 0. Try to change your index to another value like 1 or 2 I bet will still focus on at index = 0. Try to test it yourself.

Comment: The output of your code snippet is the exact issue I'm having with focus. It will always focus at index = 0.

Comment: @Paleo - I also tried to use your suggestion using watch like this
watch: {
            commentItems: function () {
               this.$nextTick(() => {
                    this.$refs.newRep[mapCredential.state.index].focus();
                });
            }
        },
but it still the same thing. It will still focus on index = 0.

Comment: @timmack I tried to change the index and it focused the right element

Comment: @HelderLucas -  can u please update your code snippet so I can see it?

Comment: @timmack just updated it. Index is now 3 which will focus the 4th textarea

Comment: @HelderLucas - sorry for the late reply...hmmm just weid in my end...that's not what the focus is behaving maybe because I'm fetching my data from the server which was queried from the database. There could be a delayed issue on binding the data into the component but anyway I'll consider your answer I'll just give a point for that...Thanks really for your help. I greatly appreciated it. Have a good one buddy!